# Как сделать постоянное получение данных из обновляющейся SQL таблицы с помощью программы на python используя pymysql

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, sql, pymysql

Надо написать код для получения alert'ов и реакции на них. Имею на данный момент такой:

```
import pymysql
import time
import os

# Устанавливаем соединение с базой данных
connection = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",
                             port=3306,
                             user="root",
                             passwd="root",
                             database="ossec")

# Создаем курсор
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Запрос на выборку значений столбцов из таблицы
query = "SELECT timestamp, rule_id, full_log  FROM alert ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25;"

# Бесконечный цикл
while True:
    try:
        # Выполняем запрос SQL
        cursor.execute(query)

        # Получаем результаты запроса
        results = cursor.fetchall()

        # Выводим результаты
        for row in results:
            timestamp_value = row[0]
            rule_id_value = row[1]
            full_log_value = row[2]

            if 53599 < rule_id_value < 53605:
                print(full_log_value)
                


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break


# Закрываем соединение с базой данных
connection.close()
```

Но в данном случае программа реагирует на изменения ТОЛЬКО после ее перезапуска, писать отдельно в try пытался, не помогает. Что делать? Как реализовать постоянную подгрузку изменений?

Comment: Что, если создавать курсор внутри цикла? И не забывать его закрывать

Comment: Нет, сожалению, такое тоже не работает